Creating bigquery tables with expiration option leads to unexpected expiration time
I'm creating a table in GBQ with an expiration timestamp as following:
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  `myproject.mydataset.testtable`
  OPTIONS (expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)))
AS
SELECT
  1 AS column_one

The expiration of the resulting table is at 7am UTC, however the output of SELECT TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) is midnight (in UTC).
Does somebody have an explanation what information I'm missing here?

The default timezone of all these date(time)-related functions is UTC according to the docs.
Indeed one would expect the expiration to be set to midnight in UTC here - and to match the result of querying the expression directly. However, it seems that GCP is internally computing the expiration time when processing the request and therefore in the timezone the request is being processed.
This can be verified:
SELECT
  TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)),
  DATE_ADD(DATE("2024-07-06", "US/Pacific"), INTERVAL 2 DAY),
  TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY), "US/Pacific"),
  TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE("UTC"), INTERVAL 2 DAY), "US/Pacific"),
  TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE("UTC"), INTERVAL 2 DAY), "UTC"),
  TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE("US/Pacific"), INTERVAL 2 DAY), "US/Pacific")

Using this one can recognize that apparently internally the calculations for the query options (in contrast to the query itself) are run in US/Pacific time.
This is a bug on GCP Side.
In general, the dependency on implicit timezones here as well as the coercion to timestamp seems to cause the issue.
For our case, we made sure to have expectations met by switching to time-relative settings:
TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 36 HOUR))

